# Ellipsis or Emphasis?

Tags: grammar

There is an example of "after" in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary:

> I can't believe she'd do that, not after all I've done for her.

In this context, "after"  means "despite". It can explain. Yet "not" is confusing me. What is the usage of "not" here?

Comment: _After_ does not mean _despite_; there's a negative there that _after_ doesn't imply. Consequently one needs a negative when using _after_ to mean the same thing. It's echoing the _not_ of _can't believe_, and it would be inferred if it weren't there, so it's OK without the _not_ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant definition of *after* in the online version of the Cambridge English Dictionary.

> following in time, place, or order:
>
> - After (= despite) everything I've done for you, is this the way you treat me?
> - After (= because of) what she did to me, I'll never trust her again.

In fact, as you can see from the words *= despite* and *= because of* that *after* does have a causal or concessive use.

Now it might have been more typical to have omitted the negative *not*:-

> I can't believe she'd do that after all I've done for her

But the speaker has instead **repeated** the negative in *I can't*.  It is a rhetorical device of repetition for emphasis.  Here what is being emphasised is the disbelief. It grabs the audience's attention, just as it grabbed yours.

Answer (score 0):

I find myself disagreeing with the two well reasoned comments above. It need not be temporal at all.

"*Not* with all I have done for her" will do just as well as *despite*. All such activity is in the past and as such appears as only temporal. The Not expresses his disbelief of her uncharacteristic response to his earnest efforts.

*Despite* itself has its own negative, meaning *in spite of it* or *against it*. When replaced by "*after all* I have done" it is natural, though not essential, to add a negation in front of it. That is the reason for the *not*.

Comment: *"Not with all I have done for her" will do just as well as despite.* So would "especially", but John Lawler's explanation seems sound. *I can* **not** *believe that after ...*